# make getSystemService() recognize our new system service

Tags: android, android-service, android-source, android-build

I'm using the book "Embedded Android".

I'm making a new System Service using AOSP(4.0.3_r1).
I want my system service to be registered in *frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/app/ContextImpl.java* so that I can use it through `getSystemService()` method.

The problem is, I can't find the ***app*** folder under ***content***:
*androidroot/frameworks/base/core/java/android/**content/app**/ContextImpl.java*
But, I found it in:
*androidroot/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java*

Are these 2 files the same? or is it just missing(the content/***app*** folder)?
Any idea on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karim wrote his book mostly orienting on Android 2.3.4 version. Something can be changed from this time. This is an example what has been changed.

> Are these 2 files the same? or is it just missing(the content/app folder)?

These are the same files.

> Any idea on what to do?

As I said the implementation has been changed. I looked into the code and here what you can change to make your code working (I can only suppose because I did not actually build my code). In the `static` block of ContextImpl class you need to add the following code:

```
registerService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE, new ServiceFetcher() {
    public Object createService(ContextImpl ctx) {
        IBinder b = ServiceManager.getService(OPERSYS_SERVICE);
        IOpersysService service = IOpersysService.Stub.asInterface(b);
        return new OpersysManager(service);
    }});
```

Comment: YES! I just tried messing around with androidroot/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java and it worked!

@Yury Thanks for the information anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SystemServer` which holds all system services' names.
You should check this link out:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Android-Adding_SystemService

Comment: I already checked that. But it uses the ServiceManager.getService() method, which is not exposed in the SDK. That's why I'm making my service available to getSystemService() method.